# Confusing yet interesting C behavior while counting size of file

Tags: c

I am writing a very simple C program to count the size of a file. I have a success in counting both text,.odt, and binary files. However, after I made some minor changes in the code I get a different result for .odt and binary files.

This is my code that gives correct results:

```
while(fgetc(pFile)!=EOF) size++;
```

And this is the one that gives me different and wrong results for binary and odt files (and I can't understand why it is different?)

```
   size=0; 

   c=fgetc(pFile);

   while(c!=EOF)
   {

      c=fgetc(pFile); 
      size++;
   }
```

Note: This code gives correct results for text files though.

This is the overall code (function) :

```
 int count(char * file)
 {
     int size;
     char c;
     FILE * pFile;

     size=0;
     c=' ';

     pFile = fopen(file, "rb");
     if(!pFile)
     {
        printf("Invalid file(%s)!\n",file); 
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
     }

     c=fgetc(pFile);
     while(c!=EOF)
     {
        c=fgetc(pFile); 
        size++;
     }
     // while(fgetc(pFile)!=EOF) size++;

     fclose(pFile);

     return size;
}
```

Comment: What's the platform, and what's your open call look like? Also, is this simply an exercise, or do you actually need the filesize for something?

Comment: For binary files `fopen` should indicate "rb" to handle `\r\n` not as a single `\n`.

Comment: Check if `c` declared as an `unsigned` type first.

Comment: How far off is the counted size from the actual file size?

Comment: This is for Ubuntu OS. And yeah i did with "rb" but still same results.

Comment: And c was not declared as unsigned. So, i just made it unsigned which interestingly halts the execution of the program.

Comment: @thesashi7: `fgetc()` returns an `int`. Is `c` defined as an `int`? You know this would be easier if you showed a complete example that reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it was the declaration of `c`.  Here is some sample code which works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int fsize(char *s)
{
    FILE *pF = NULL;
    int c = 0;  /* declaring this as char will bring you funny results */
    int iSize = 0;

    pF = fopen(s, "r");
    if (! pF)
    {
        perror("Cannot open file");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(pF, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(EOF != (c = fgetc(pF)))
        iSize ++;

    fclose(pF);

    return iSize;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 1; argc > i; i ++)
        printf("%10d  %s\n", fsize(argv[i]), argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bravo! You are right shinkou. It was the declaration of c. I changed it to int and it works.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what do you mean by " count the size of a file".
But if you want the file size,

Following code will do I hope.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sbuf;

stat(filepath, &sbuf);

printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)sbuf.st_size);
```

Comment: This solution does not address the OP's question concerning the difference between their 2 implementations.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are getting the file size a little lesser than the actual size.
  The reason i believe causing that is the `c=fgetc(pFile);` being written twice. One outside while and one inside. The control executes the first `c=fgetc(pFile);`, goes into while and again inside while executes `c=fgetc(pFile);` without incrementing size.

```
   size=0; 
   c=fgetc(pFile);
   if(c!=EOF)
   {
     size++;
   }
   while(c!=EOF)
   {

      c=fgetc(pFile); 
      size++;
   }
```

Here, if the file is empty fgetc will return a EOF. So we increment only if c is returned with a value other than EOF.
  This should fix that. Hope this helped.

Comment: Consider an empty file (size = 0). This code will not produce the correct value

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you @EdHeal, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Still not right - need to check for EOF. Code checks for not the null character (0)

Comment: I did not get why would we need to do that. A file which has EOF as the first character would be an empty file, right? Hence the value of c would be NULL which would skip the incrementing of size. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna: `fgetc()` would return EOF which is not the same as NULL. You're just guessing aren't you?

Comment: Okie. I had mistaken. `fgetc()` was something i had come across recently. I had mistaken that it would return NULL like fgets() which returns NULL. Thank you both @EdHeal and @Blastfurnace.